# How do I get this policy to work in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I have a very basic policy

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Comment;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class CommentPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function update(User $user, Comment $comment)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I call it in a view

```
@can('update', $comment)
Edit
@endcan
```

I register it

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        App\Models\Comment::class => App\Policies\CommentPolicy::class,
    ];
```

Even though it should always show because I've hardcoded `true`, nothing shows

Answer (score 0):

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        \App\Models\Comment::class => \App\Policies\CommentPolicy::class,
    ];
```

I forgot the backslashes at the beginning